# Erro execução log4j selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, intellij-idea

Sou novato em testes automatizados e estou criando um script de testes no selenium e quando vou executar estou tendo esta resposta de erro:

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.easetech.easytest.loader.CSVDataLoader).  
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
```

Não faço ideia do que seja esse `log4j`.
Será que alguém consegue me ajudar?

O meu código está muito grande, por isso não vou inseri-lo aqui, mas se precisar de algum trecho eu posto aqui.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Allan, **log4j** é uma ferramenta de logging bastante utilizada, principalmente em java.

Esse problema deve se dar ao arquivo de configuração (log4j.properties ou log4j.xml) do seu projeto, no stackoverflow em inglês tem um problema extremamente semelhante ao seu, da uma olhada aqui, provavelmente a resposta marcada como certa vai te salvar.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1140498/8260882

Inclusive na resposta tem um link pra documentação.

*Se possível edita sua pergunta com qual versão do **log4j** você esta usando, e um pouco mais de background seria bom, do tipo estava funcionando antes e parou? Você modificou algo? Você copiou código de outra classe? E só esta quebrando nessa?*

Comment: Consegui resolver o problema, adicionei uma linha de código que importou este log4j, sendo que eu não uso esta ferramenta no meu projeto. Após remover o import consegui executar o teste normalmente.